# In JavaScript, once the user submit a value, how do I keep input value printed?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, input

I am trying to accomplish the following tasks shown in the image attached. 
As you can see, there are 5 submissions, how can I accomplish to keep all 5 submissions printed on the page? So far, I can only keep 1 submission, but as soon as I submit another one, it replaces it. 
This is my `code`.

````
var i = ",";
var listItem = " ";
var count = 0;

document.getElementById("sButton").addEventListener("click", processInput, false);

function processInput() {

    if (listItem = document.getElementById("inputText").value) {

        var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = inputValue + ",";
    }

    else {
        (document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = " ");
    }

    if (count++ == 4) {            
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Gracias por sus 
                     sugerencias."
    }
}```

[Here, right below the textbox, it's showing 5 items/inputs that were submitted. How do I keep those and not lose them when another input is submitted?][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zRuT.png
````

Comment: Use an array to collect the given inputs. Use thereafter the ˋjoin(“, “)ˋ method on that array to concatenate things and assign it to the innerHTML.

Comment: I was able to get working with one of the answers below.  All I had to do was to add a + to the = on the `document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = inputValue + ","`

Comment: Made the change to `document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += inputValue + ","`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the keep the existing value by concatenating with previous. Don't write it to innerHTML but concat it with previous value. Please override following code snippit.

```js
if (listItem = document.getElementById("inputText").value) {

  var inputValue = document.getElementById("inputText").value;
  document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += inputValue + ",";
} else {
  (document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = "");
}

if (count++ == 4) {

  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Gracias por sus 
  sugerencias.
  "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Track the values in an array, separate from the HTML. When an item is added, push it into the values array and then update the displayed text:

```js
// the text input
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// an array to keep track of the values
const values = [];

// form submission handler that pushes the new value into the values array
function handleSubmit(e) {
  // prevent actual form submission
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  
  // append the new value
  if (input.value.trim().length) {
    values.push( input.value );
  }

  // reset the input
  input.value = '';
  
  // update the display
  updateDisplay(values);
}

// update the display from the given values
function updateDisplay (values) {
  // find the container for the display list
  const list = document.getElementById('list');

  // render the new text
  list.innerText = values.join(', ');
  
  const count = document.getElementById('count');
  count.innerText = values.length > 4
    ? 'Gracias por sus sugerencias.'
    : `You have ${values.length} values!`;
}
```

```html
<div id="list">

</div>
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <input />
  <button>Add a value</button>
</form>

<div id="count"></div>
```

Comment: I was able to make the adjustments by adding a "+" to the "=" on the code line `document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = inputValue + ","` making it out to be `document.getElementById("label").innerHTML += inputValue + ","`